# Requiring modules from requirejs (with babeljs plugin) in es6 scripts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, requirejs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm trying to use [RequireJS babel plugin](https://github.com/mikach/requirejs-babel) along with [ReactJS](https://facebook.github.io/react/) to make a simple class in es6 but cant figure out how to [Import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) or Require Reacts library from [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) while also exporting the class to use in another script.

Below is the jsbin of what i've done so far but currently it errors when i get to the es6 class because the export is inside the require call but if i remove the require call React.Component wont exist.

[HTML](https://jsbin.com/dagihecosi/2/edit?html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.2/require.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://output.jsbin.com/guvalasowi.js"></script>
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="a-div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

[RequireJS Config](https://jsbin.com/guvalasowi.js)

```
require({
  paths: {
    es6: "https://cdn.rawgit.com/mikach/requirejs-babel/master/es6",
    babel: "https://cdn.rawgit.com/mikach/requirejs-babel/master/babel-5.8.34.min",
    react: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react-with-addons.min",
    reactDOM: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react-dom.min",
    test: "https://output.jsbin.com/sahudexegu"
  }
});
require(['es6!test', 'reactDOM'], function(test, ReactDOM){
  ReactDOM.render(
    table,
    document.getElementById("a-div")
  );
});
```

[Test Module (es6 class)](https://jsbin.com/sahudexegu.js)

```
require(['react'], function(React){
    class Welcome extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return <h1>Hello</h1>;
      }
    };

    export {Welcome};
});
```

tl;dr: How do you require modules from requirejs when inside es6 scripts and still export a class object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, to answer your main question, the export can done like this:

```
import React from 'react';

class Welcome extends React.Component {
    render() {
         return (
            <h1>Hello</h1>
         );
    }
}

export default Welcome
```

The usage of the component (had some trouble with your ReactDOM include as it was):

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
    'es6': "bower_components/requirejs-babel/es6",
    'babel': "babel-5.8.34.min",
    'react': 'https://unpkg.com/react@15.3.2/dist/react',
    'react-dom': 'https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.3.2/dist/react-dom',
    'test': "test"
  }
});


requirejs(['es6!test', 'react', 'react-dom'], function(test,  React, ReactDOM) {

  var Welcome = test.default;

  ReactDOM.render(
    <Welcome />,
    document.getElementById("a-div")
  );

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Working example below, one thing i did have to change from the accepted answer was the use of jsx in the requirejs config script.

[HTML](https://jsbin.com/lidegodiru)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.2/require.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://output.jsbin.com/zeyajapoxa.js"></script>
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="a-div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

[RequireJS Config](https://jsbin.com/zeyajapoxa)

```
require({
  paths: {
    es6: "https://cdn.rawgit.com/mikach/requirejs-babel/master/es6",
    babel: "https://cdn.rawgit.com/mikach/requirejs-babel/master/babel-5.8.34.min",
    react: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react-with-addons",
    'react-dom': "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react-dom",
    test: "https://output.jsbin.com/poremuqupu"
  }
});
requirejs(['es6!test', 'react', 'react-dom'], function(test,  React, ReactDOM) {
  console.log(arguments)
  //var Welcome = test.default;
  console.log(test)

  ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement(test, test),
    document.getElementById("a-div")
  );
});
```

[Es6 Class](https://jsbin.com/poremuqupu/edit?js,output)

```
import React from 'react';

class Welcome extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello</h1>;
  }
};

export default Welcome
```